# Dough for edible bowls, plates

Tags: baking, dough

I want to bake edible bowls that go with e.g. salad or snacks, that is, I need a non-sweet, bread-like dough that gets reasonably hard when baked but is still somewhat edible.

Is there some classic technique, a special ingredient, or just a general direction to go for a such dough?

Comment: Bread bowls for thick soup or stew are common, but around here they're round loaves that have the center cut out. Is that not what you want? Look into medieval trenchers too. Any flatbread can be molded into a bread shape. Can you give us an idea of the aesthetic you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It is not really what I have in mind. I would like the dough to get rather dry and sturdy, much like dry waffles or ice cream cones, and I imagined it to be rather shapeable, that is, not rising a lot.

Comment: What about a pastry shell? https://www.google.com/search?q=pastry+shells&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj398Dl8NjUAhVS1WMKHeRtAIsQ_AUICygC&biw=1280&bih=691

Comment: That is a nice idea, thank you. But they are necessarily sweet, are they not? I thought about using rye flour and not much else. That will get hard, will it not? What about italian grissini (dough)?

Comment: Pastry shells are not generally sweet, no. They are often filled with savory foods. Any bread will stale if left out. Yes, the Italian Grissini dough looks like you could use it like this: http://www.odlums.ie/recipes/bread-bowls-tomato-soup/

Comment: Thanks, that looks great. I would accept that as an answer.

Comment: Uncooked tortillas work very well.

Comment: Dough plates sound like a PITA to make.

Comment: @thrig punny, very punny...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want trenchers (add "recipe" when searching to weed out the digging tools) as the bread plates of old were called. Since recipe requests are off-topic, I won't include a recipe, but your favorite search engine will provide many.

You could also do something in the puff pasty shell line, for a different texture - easier to eat but also less durable.

A savory pizzelle would also fit - you have to form those when hot, before they harden, and the standard pizzelle maker limits the size, but there might be ways around that limitation.

You can also steam and then bake tacos (which you can either purchase or make) into various shapes by laying them in or over something that shapes them the way you like when baking.

I don't know if there's a way to get pappadums soft enough to shape without cracking before heating and hardening/blistering - though they can be somewhat pliable when hot, they are prone to crack.

Answer (score 0):

Hot-water shortcrust can be made very shapeable and firm, yet well edible, if the fat ratio and baking time are well chosen - experimentation is advised. Even thickness is important, so do use a rolling pin: thinner sections will overbake, and overbaked HWS can easily turn molar breaking hard. Also, use caution making the fat-water mixture - this can unexpectedly go ballistic on you.